# Codeigniter Get Language Key variables in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller, internationalization

how can i print language key in controller in Codeigniter.
I usually use

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');

$this->lang->line('language_key');
```

To get the key and after pass it to the view, for example:

```
$data["language_msg"] = $this->lang->line("msg_hello_english");
        $this->load->view('language_view', $data);
```

But what if i want to use the key in the controller ?
I mean i have to get the key and after echo that in the controller which will print the text value in the page, when it is called ?

I really need help about this !

Thank you so much,

federico

Answer (score 1):

Simply echo this:

```
echo $this->lang->line("msg_hello_english");
```

or use the variable anyway you want to.

However, generally you don't want to do this directly from your controller - that's what you have views for. If you are doing much of that, consider if you are making a bad design pattern.